# Получить значение тега

Tags: html, python, selenium

Python - Selenium. Необходимо получить значение тега span - вариант снизу не работает.

```
<div class = "1">
  <button class = "2">
    <span>8</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

```
current_num = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="2"]/span/text()')
print (current_num)
```

Хотелось бы получить на выходе - "8".

Comment: а что по факту вы получаете на выхоже?

Comment: Не может определить элемент. Стоит упомянуть. что дерево довольно большое и   до div есть много объектов.

Comment: Элемент находит, но данная запись не работает.

Comment: что значит данная запись не работает? если элемент нужный находит, то значит и текст должен с него забраться корректно

Comment: Так получилось `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="2"]/span').text` Данная форма возвращает "3 человека". Есть ли какой-нибудь вариант, как откинуть текст после числа - чтобы оставалось только "3"?

Comment: я уверен, что есть, но это уже не в рамках данного вопроса. я считаю, что данный вопрос стоит закрыть, т.к. он не полезен остальным участникам сообщества